# T-SQL DELETE Statement returns Subquery hint "returns more than one value..."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question on MS SQL's DELETE statement.

I pose the following statement:

```
DELETE [Database].[dbo].[ADDRESSES]
  WHERE USERGROUP = 'GR_SALES';
GO
```

The SSMS throws out the following hint: (regular hint, when a subquery returns more than one value:

```
Message 512, Level 16, Status 1, procedure After Update, row 27

The Subquery returns more than one value...
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `DELETE FROM [Database].[dbo].[ADDRESSES]
  WHERE USERGROUP = 'GR_SALES';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words `after update` in the hint strongly suggests that this table has a trigger being called.

My best guess is that the trigger has both update and delete actions; your `DELETE` query causes it to fire, at which point SQL Server parses the update action even though it isn't relevant here. If this is correct, running an `UPDATE` query will probably cause an actual error from within the trigger.